# Multi-time frame strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to create a strategy where it buys if the MA200 crosses below the price on the 1-hour timeframe. The strategy sells if: MA200 crosses above price in 1-hour timeframe, and MA9 is greater than the price on the 1-week timeframe, and MA200 is greater than the price on the 4-hour timeframe. However, it's not working properly and the plots of the larger time-frames distort the chart to where I cannot see the candlesticks.

```
strategy('Multi Time-Frame Analysis',
     overlay=true,
     initial_capital=1000,
     default_qty_value=30,
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity,
     commission_type=strategy.commission.percent,
     commission_value=0.1)

timePeriod = time >= timestamp(syminfo.timezone, 2022, 6, 24, 02, 09)
notInTrade = strategy.position_size <= 0


buyCondition1 = ta.ema(close, 200) //< close   //1 hour
buyFrame1Hour = request.security("BTC", "60", buyCondition1 < close)
plot(buyCondition1, color = color.purple)

if (buyFrame1Hour and notInTrade and timePeriod)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    //when = buyCondition1


sellCondition1 = ta.ema(close, 200)  //1 hour
sellCondition2 = ta.ema(close, 9)    //1 week
sellCondition3 = ta.ema(close, 200)  //4 hours

timeFrame1Hour = request.security("BTC", "60", sellCondition1)   //1 hour
timeFrame1Week = request.security("BTC", "1W", sellCondition2)   //1 week
timeFrame4Hour = request.security("BTC", "240", sellCondition3)  //4 hours
//plot(timeFrame1Hour, color = color.red)
//plot(timeFrame1Week, color = color.blue)
//plot(timeFrame4Hour, color = color.green)

if (timeFrame1Hour and timeFrame1Week and timeFrame4Hour and notInTrade and timePeriod)
    strategy.exit(id = "stoploss", stop = PriceStop, limit = takeProfit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be issue with how you are generating the conditions. Buy and sell should check for crossunder and crossover on 200 1H EMA. Example below

```
//@version=5
strategy('Multi Time-Frame Analysis',  overlay=true)



buyCondition1 = ta.crossunder(ta.ema(close, 200),close)   //1 hour
expr=ta.ema(close,200)
ema200 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", expr)
buyFrame1Hour = ta.crossunder(ema200,close)

plot(ema200, color = color.purple)

if (buyFrame1Hour )
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

sellCondition2 = (ta.ema(close, 9)>close)    //1 week
sellCondition3 = (ta.ema(close, 200)>close)  //4 hours

timeFrame1Hour = ta.crossover(ema200,close)   //1 hour
timeFrame1Week = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1W", sellCondition2)   //1 week
timeFrame4Hour = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", sellCondition3)  //4 hours

if (timeFrame1Hour and timeFrame1Week and timeFrame4Hour)
    strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short)
```